# Speeding up lots of markers even quicker

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm currently in the process of re launching my site which is primarily a site that is a giant Google Map with LOTS of markers (Currently around 34,000 and estimated to be at 50,000+ by the end of 2013 [calculated using average additions a day]).

Since launch I have been improving my skills and optimising by using methods such as Gzip, removing unneeded data from the data file that the site uses and clustering the data.

The development site can be viewed at http://dev.rastrack.co.uk

What would I be able to do, to speed up the page load even more. From what I can tell the limitation is now where the client has to cluster all the markers.

I can host and write PHP code to do the job if this is possible. The data is stored as a Json string for each marker in MongoDB.

Comment: Have you seen [Too Many Markers!](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers) in the documentation?

Comment: Yes and I am using the marker cluster method. The FusionTablesLayer I can't use as I am using my own hosted database.